# Quadrupling Power in a Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

If I have a heating wire with resistance $R$ to be connected across a constant potential difference $V$, it would seem like cutting the wire into two (thus each having half the resistance) and connecting both across the voltage gap would quadruple the power output according to $P = \frac{V^2}{R}$.

Why is this not such a good idea?
I thought that it was because the current going through the wires would double, but that doesn't seem too bad. What actually makes this not such a good idea?

Comment: Who says it is not a good idea? Only problem would be if the wires cannot handle the power and melt.

Comment: "not a good idea", you mean that it heats up fast?

Comment: the power would double

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't seem too bad"? can you state it scientifically, instead of using emotional adjective? :-)

Comment: @MahderT: the power in _each wire_ would double, but now you've got two wires. So it would quadruple, as OP said.

Comment: I guess it would be great if I was building a heater but "Why is this not a good idea?" is how the textbook puts it and besides a high current going through the wire and damaging it, I don't know why it would not be a good idea.

Comment: "good idea" by what objective criteria?  It's a fact that cutting the wire in two and placing the resulting half-length segments in parallel will quarter the equivalent resistance and thus, quadruple the power supplied for a given voltage across but... if this is what you *want to accomplish* then, I think, this is *good*; if it is opposite that which you wish to accomplish then, I think, this is *bad*.

Comment: So having 4 1/4Ω resistors would dissipate 16x more power than a 1Ω resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is completely correct.  Two 1/2 R resistors in parallel will dissipate 4x the power of a 1 R resistor at the same applied voltage.

Whether that is "good" or not depends on whether the wire can handle the extra heat, whether the power supply can supply the extra current, whether the extra heat is desirable, whether using the extra power is acceptable, etc.  Clearly you haven't told us enough to be able to judge that.